# How to delete a video after it has been watched completely?

Tags: video, mplayer

I watch most of my TV news on my computer.
The videos are downloaded by my RSS reader and stored on disk until I decide to watch them.

The files look like this:

```
130704_hjo_446k_p20v11.mp4
130706_hjo_446k_p20v11.mp4
130708_hjo_446k_p20v11.mp4
```

The thing is I don't watch them daily, but whenever I feel like it. So sometimes I watch one sometimes three in a row.I watch them normally with `mplayer2` by executing the following:

```
mplayer *hjo*.mp4
```

My problem is I always forget to delete the already watched files and then I have to remember when I last watched or I have to rewatch until I find the new files.

Now I am looking for a script or program which marks the completely watched files. As far as I know `mplayer2` can't do this, since there is no hook to check if the video was watched to the end.

Comment: As variant: `for file in *hjo*.mp4; do mplayer $file && rm -f $file; done`

Comment: As an option you can use `rm -i` to get user confirmation before deletion.

Comment: The problem is when I need to stop watching and quit mplayer the exit code is also 0 and since sometimes I have 3 hours or more of news I want to be able to quit watching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to install the package `mplayer-resumer`. This will allow you to resume a video from where you left off. When you're done watching the videos using this wrapper script, you can then safely delete them.

```
$ mplayer-resumer options path/to/file
```

- [Automatic resuming from where you left off - tips tricks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MPlayer#Automatic_resuming_from_where_you_left_off)
- [mplayer-resumer on github](https://github.com/graysky2/mplayer-resumer)

*excerpt from main site on rationale*

> Watching 90 % of a video and stopping causes you to return to the
>   beginning again the next time you watch it. Remembering where you were
>   in the video and resuming at that position is a much nicer behavior
>   for the user. By default, mplayer spits out timecode information that
>   tells you where you are in the video, to the tenth of a second.
>   Mplayer also supports a seek feature on the command-line. We can make
>   use of these features to write an mplayer wrapper that will remember
>   the last position in a video file and resume to it on playback.

Comment: A that looks promising. But I need to port it to FreeBSD. I should have mentioned that. :)

Comment: @RaphaelAhrens - it's just a Perl script so it should be pretty easy.